# How do I store the aggregation result into another database

Tags: mongodb

I can store an aggregation result into another collection **within the same database**.

But how can I store the result **into another database**?

This is for copying a collection into another database:

```
use test1;
db["user_data"].find().forEach(
  function(d){ db.getSiblingDB("test2")['user_data'].insert(d); 
});
```

Aggregation function:

```
pipeline = [
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        '$year': '$birthday'
      },
      'count': {
        '$sum': 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$sort': {
      '_id': 1
    }
  }, {
    '$out': output_collection
  }
];
cur = db[source_collection].runCommand('aggregate', {
  pipeline: pipeline,
  allowDiskUse: true
});
```

Answer (score 3):

After running the aggregation to the output collection, you need to run another command that clones the collection to another database using [**`db.cloneCollection()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.cloneCollection/) as follows:

```
db.runCommand({ 
    cloneCollection: "test.output_collection", 
    from: "mongodb.example.net:27017", 
    query: { active: true } 
})
```

The above copies the `output_collection` collection from the `test` database on the server at `mongodb.example.net`. The operation only copies documents that satisfy the query `{ active: true }` but the query arguments is optional. **`cloneCollection`** always copies indexes.

Answer (score 3):

Starting `Mongo 4.2`, the new [`$merge`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) aggregation operator can be used to write the result of an aggregation pipeline to the specified collection *within another database*:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // { $group: { "_id": { $year: "$birthday" }, "count": { $sum: 1 } } },
  // { $sort: { "_id": 1 } },
  { $merge: { into: { db: "to", coll: "collection" } } }
])
```

Note that if the targeted collection already contains records, the `$merge` operator comes with [many options](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#syntax) to specify how to merge inserted records conflicting with existing records.

Comment: can be done with `$out` as well: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#syntax